# Number formating fraction in Python

Tags: python, number-formatting, fractions

I'm used to formatting fractions in Google Sheets as '# ##/##', is there any way to do the same in Python or do I have to program it?

I have tried:

```
F'Value: {Fraction(a / b).limit_denominator()}'
```

Gives for example: '3/2'

I would like: '1 1/2' in this case.

Comment: You can write `Fraction(a, b)` without having to worry about floating-point error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `divmod` to separate the integer and fractional parts. From there it's a simple matter of using the `format` method.

```
>>> f = Fraction(3, 2)
>>> '{} {}'.format(*divmod(f, 1))
'1 1/2'
```

Comment: Yes thank you, but then you will have to add logic to suppress zero values in the resulting string?  (0 1/2, 1 0, 0 0 and so on.) No ready to use formatting in other words?

Comment: That's wasn't a requirement in your original question. But yes, you'll need to write a function to handle those special cases, well, specially.

Comment: One place this fails, though, is for negative numbers, which require you to divide by -1, not 1.